# Print Bleed/Trim Size

Tags: cmyk, rgb

I have designed an infographic in an A4 size. in this I have kept a simple dark green colour sleek footer keeping in mind that it will be cut in trimming in printing. But now the client have asked to put up his Ph., email & website on that bottom sleek footer. But I am not sure how to send a sample to the client. He needs it for both web and print. Do I have to make two files in this case? one for web and another for print as his contact details will be coming at the bottom of the page but in printing it will be cut. Can anyone help pls???

Comment: I dont understand the problem?!

Comment: I think you need to understand what are trim marks (http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55325/why-do-some-printed-documents-have-those-target-like-lines-in-their-corners/55338#55338), what is bleed (http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55905/how-can-i-determine-how-much-bleed-to-use/55907#55907) and finally how to output 2 different PDF from the same file. You'll need to adjust your design to make sure nothing is cut on the print-ready... Then once this is done, use that file to export an optimized PDF or a JPG for web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of this question seems to have nothing to do with what you're asking.

Do you need to know the trim/bleed sizes?  That's something you need to get from your printer.

If you're asking what to do, because your client needs this for both web and print use, then **yes, you will definitely need two files**.

Depending on what makes up most of your design (photos, text, graphics, etc.), you'll usually want to save the web version as a JPG or PNG.  Use the *Save For Web* options (if using Adobe) and adjust your settings for the best image quality and lowest file size.  Since this is an infographic, **I would suggest saving as a PNG**, assuming it is made up of mostly text and graphics (photographs are better as JPG).

For the print version, you will need to ask the printer what they require, as far as file type and dimensions are concerned.  I just did a quick Google search and a **standard bleed for the A4 size is 3mm** with a safe area of 5mm inside the trim.  You will most likely want to save it at 300 DPI and in CKYM color mode, but the file type depends on the printer.  Usually PDF is a safe bet, but you never know.  They may ask for something else.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know the standard trim/bleed sizes & how to work for both rgb and cmyk. I Have deigned my infographic in cmyk mode bcoz its easy to convert from cmyk to rgb in terms of colours getting diffrnt. Presently, inside of my page I have left 12 mm size on all the 4 sides of my A4 size page.  So, I assume that it is safe enough bleed size? So it means that if we are designing for both modes i.e rgb and cmyk and if our design demand is towards the edge/bottom of the page then we have to design & align our artwork seperately in two files. one acc. to rgb & another according to CMYK?

Comment: Color mode means nothing, with respect to document size or the positioning of your elements within the document.  Get the information from your printer, regarding what sizes and file format they require for print.  **Design the document to those settings.**  Save a version in whichever format they require for print (your CMYK one) and then save another version for the web (RGB) with the same dimensions (72 dpi instead of 300 though).  Your color space has no impact on how your design should be laid out. @Designmate

Comment: I want to ask if I am doing it correct. Making any artwork for both web and print like I am doing an infographic in illustrator, then what I am doing is :

Comment: I want to ask if I am doing it correct. Making any artwork for both web and print like I am doing an infographic in illustrator, then what I am doing is as below :

Comment: 1. Creating an a4 size file at 300 dpi at CMYK mode.  
2. leaving 12mm on all four sides inside my file. 
3. Sending the sample to client in jpg in cmyk mode (or it should be in rgb mode as save for web)??? 
4. Then when it will be finalised then I will make another copy of this cmyk artwork and convert its document 

colour mode to RGB and save it at 72 ppi? and while doing this I will have to adjust the colours as they do change 

when converted frm cmyk to rgb. 
Hope this method will be correct. Will appreciate your reply.

Comment: @Designmate, send the client a 72dpi JPG in RGB mode for his web use.  Then, send them a PDF at 300dpi in CMYK for their print use.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making the infographic for both web and print then yes you will need 2 files. That may be an export to a jpg and PDF, that depends on the type of graphic it is and what the printer wants. The web file will be RGB and the print file CMYK.

If the client has asked you to include his contact information on the footer, then you must redesign the infographic to make space for those details. But that discussion is between you and the client and whatever agreement you guys made when starting the project.