# How to achieve contrast in a black-on-black design

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, cmyk, black

I'm trying to achieve a black-on-black design on a business card. See link here:  [AHC 180 Youth Ministry Business Card](http://www.cccdtp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/black-on-black-design.jpg). The large black arrow and the grunge splotches are a rich black of 40-40-40-100, and the card background is 0-0-0-95. The card is being printed offset and UV coated, probably via an online printer (I'm ordering them through a third party and don't have access to the printer.) It's important that there be enough contrast between the blacks so that the rich black portions are distinguishable, but I still want the background to have a black/almost black appearance. Would I be better to use some version of a rich gray for the background rather than a 95% (or lower) black? I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: I tried to add the image within the question for you -- odd issues. #1) I would have **never** known there are variations in the dark areas without *reading* what you've typed. I see almost no difference in the image you linked to. #2) If I add your link as an image here, the colors are **really** bad. #3) I download your image, opened in Photoshop and the contrast changes **dramatically**. So, I'm wondering if the image you linked to may be using some odd ICC profile. I realize this doesn't answer your question. But it does make me wonder how accurately the image you linked to is displaying.

Comment: This all may be due to the CMYK color space of your jpg though.

Comment: I noticed it was difficult to distinguish the colors on the jpeg, but it's very clear in the Ai file I created it in, and it was very clear on my inkjet printer. None of which, unfortunately, helps me know how it's going to print on an offset press. :/

Comment: It's very clear when opening the image in Photoshop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't use a black only at 95%](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/what-kind-of-black-should-i-use-when-designing-for-cmyk-print/55333#55333).... make 2 different rich black.

One could be 40-40-40-100 and the other 30-30-30-90.

**Personally I recommend you use a bit more Cyan in your recipes** rather than making all your CMY values equal: if the printer is not well calibrated (or is digital), a black with more cyan will still look steel black and not dark brown (eg. 40-30-30-100 and 35-25-25-90). You don't need to use a 10% difference, 5% more of cyan is enough.

Usually, if you have a 10-15% difference in your black, it will give a nice soft contrast and will not really look gray. 5% is risky and might not be clearly visible; it could work well though if you were using a spot varnish.

With the 2 rich black recipes I suggested you it should look similar to your example.

Also, when you add a lamination or varnish, it can make the colors little bit darker. Not much, but enough to lose some contrast if you use a 5% difference only between your 2 blacks!

[image: Rich black on rich black card sample]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you go with a deep gray instead of 95% black. If your black arrow and splotches are too subtle, they'll look like a mistake rather than a purposeful design decision. A little more contrast will be more visually appealing and more likely to print well.

Another option is to spec out a spot UV coating, rather than having the entire card UV coated. In the case of a spot coat, you'll be able to highlight your design without having different shades of black.

[image]

Comment: Spot UV would be great, but it's not an option here. Can you please define for me "deep gray" in CMYK terms?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that  0-0-0-95 is a halftone of black. So I don't think it's what you'd want. At best, you'd want to use a rich gray and a rich black. What specific rich black and rich gray is hard to say as it could depend on the printer.

Note that subtle black-on-black designs are usually done as clear coats such as UV coating or spot color inks (two separate, but solid colors of black)

As for the sample image, that is *so* subtle that I don't think you're going to get results you are going to be happy with using only CMYK. However, one thing to try would be to use 100% black and a Rich Black. The rich black will be darker than the 100% black in most cases.