# overprint showing wrong in output preview on different profiles

Tags: adobe-indesign, adobe-acrobat, overprint, simulation

im having a problem concerning overprinting and the overprinting preview in acrobat pro 11.
i have a sample document. exported with indesign to "ISO coated v2 (ECI)" and having the profile embedded.
[image: you see a test document]

the cursor is on the 70% black text.
but when i switch to coated fogra27 as the simulation profile the overprint simulation gets messed up (the cursor is on the same position as it was before!) .
[image]

the overprint has gone. it appears as if the photo underneath the text is being knocked out.
it is the same problem when i export it to coated FOGRA27. when simulating another profile the overprinting becomes knocked out.
and the print-service didn't do overprinting neither when i gave him the "ISO coated v2 (ECI)" document.
does this always happen when not the right profile is used (my printer didn't have the "ISO coated v2 (ECI)" profile but the "fogra27" one)?
thanks for the help in advance!
clemens

Comment: I don't know why you're having this issue. But it's normal some printers ignore your overprint unless you specify it; lot of designers actually have no clue about trapping and put overprint on everything black. That's why printers might remove them automatically. You can try to find out why you have this issue, unfortunately I can't help you without seeing how you created your file. But there's other ways to "force" an overprint effect if you don't trust the printer: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58206/indesign-overprinting-white-at-a-guangzhou-printshop/58209#58209

Comment: how do you specify overprinting? you mean by clarifying it with the printer?
i think in my case transparency works, too. at about 50% they mix up comparably

Comment: You tell the printer "I have overprint trapping that needs to stay there" and you tell them where. Transparency is not a real overprinting and you can lose some of the transparency depending how you saved your PDF.