# Choosing the right black for laser monochrome print

Tags: color, print-design

Let's suppose that we have a monochrome *laser* printer and we want to print a project.

Which is the "right" type of black described by RGB and/or CMYK values that we have to choose in our editing software (e.g. Illustrator/PShop, etc), in order to achieve the true—not fade—black delivered by the printer by default? without being necessary to fine tune the amount of black in print settings. Any recommendations?

I've read [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/5612/56335) but I guess that there is a (color) difference between a black printed by a CMYK  machine and a black printed on the paper by a monochrome printer. Otherwise, [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2999/56335) could answer my Q.

Comment: This will depend on the printer driver surely, which depends on what printer you have. And what OS you're running Illustrator/Photoshop on.

Comment: I think you can find the answer there: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5611/what-cmyk-values-should-i-use-for-rich-black-and-how-should-i-handle-tints-shad

Comment: @ Andrew There is indeed an option in the printer driver to choose a deep or softer black but... I am referring at the pre-print phase; As long as a black could be described by #000000 in web for example and in (offset) print industry black is defined by other values, I was just wondering if there is a similarity in approaching this.

Comment: @dimshik not so sure if this it's also the same for monochrome laser printers; I'll have a good look, thanks.

Comment: I think that probably the safest is simply CMYK 0,0,0,100, but Andrew Leach is right: the printer driver is going to be the arbiter of this and probably not configurable. Note that built tones are probably going to be screened.

Comment: This is fairly easy to test. Make an image in your software that is 100% black and print it. How does it look?

Comment: @Yorik there is an option PrintDensity (Black)> -10 ..10, default 0. DA01, black, but compared to what? The point is to find at a theoretically level (not mesured by the eye) if we can talk about a "rich black" in laser monochrome printing, (e.g. 60/60/40/100, or 40/30/30/100). In other words, could these or other black values modify the default black of the laser printer—not taking in discussion the custom density black driver settings—turning the _black_ into _less black_ OR no matter what _black_ we will use, the printer will deliver the same black made by the above mentioned settings?

Comment: My point is that anything we learn from this will be applicable to the specific model and even driver revision for the printer and may not have any user configurability. In my personal experience, I have seen devices determine that there are raster images and therefore the whole thing must be a photo, so the fonts get screened. Me? I design in greyscale for 1-color output.

Comment: @Yorik thank you, I guess that this could be an elegant approach, designing/converting in greyscale.